# Are file scoped static objects zero initialized before static initialization occurs for the owning translation unit?

Tags: c++, static, initialization, standards

In file maybe_use_foo.cpp:

```
namespace {
    class Foo { /* ... */ };
    Foo* const the_foo = new Foo;
}

void funtion_callable_from_another_tu_during_process_wide_initialization() {
    // If we haven't yet run static initialization for this TU,
    // but some other static initializer called us, ignore the request.
    if (!the_foo)
      return;

    // OK, static initializers for this TU have run, foo exists, use it.
    the_foo->doSomething();
}
```

So, independently of whether or not the above is advisable, does it always work? It seem to me that it assumes that statics are zero-initialized before the static initialization for the TU runs. Does the C++ standard (C++03? C++11?) guarantee that?

Another way to ask the question would be to ask what sequence of values, when interpreted as a Foo*, are held in the storage for 'the_foo'. Is it definitely {NULL/nullptr, new Foo}, or is it {undefined, new Foo}, or even something else?

Please don't suggest other ways of organizing: I'm not looking for suggestions on how to do this better, I'm looking for a deeper understanding of the legality of the technique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++11

[basic.start.init]/2

> Variables with static storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage duration (3.7.2) shall be zero-initialized (8.5) before any other initialization takes place.
>
> [...]
>
> Together, zero-initialization and constant initialization are called *static initialization*; all other initialization is *dynamic initialization*. Static initialization shall be performed before any dynamic initialization takes place.

That is, yes, the variables are zero-initialized, but no, they're not zero-initialized *before* static initialization (but as part of static initialization).

---

The function in the OP will only be called during during dynamic initialization, as it is not called during zero-initialization and had to be a `constexpr` function to be part of constant initialization.

Comment: Hold on what about `Loki  loki(5);` Is that Zero-Initialized before it is dynamically initialized using the constructor. The constructor is not a `constexpr`. So does not qualify for `constant-initialization`

Comment: @LokiAstari Semantically, even constant-initialized non-local variables are zero-initialized first. And yes, non-local variables of class type will also be zero-initialized, this however means (for non-union types) a recursive zero-initialization of each member (and padding). Essentially, .bss However, constant and even dynamic initialization may also be applied at compile-time under some circumstances ("if it doesn't break anything"), which would put it in the .data segment.

Comment: OK. See it now. Zero-Initialization does not require a constructor. It just zeros the memory.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the C++03 standard explains in [basic.start.init]:

> Objects with static storage duration (3.7.1) shall be zero-initialized (8.5) before any other initialization takes place.

8.5.1 explains:

> To zero-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> — if T is a scalar type (3.9), the object is set to the value of 0 (zero) converted to T;
>
> [..]

Answer (score 0):

Your code can cause errors. Linkers usually don't try to deeply understand initialization portions in seperate modules. Try better to provide the variable via static function, for example

```
namespace {
    Foo* the_foo() {
        static Foo* g_ = new Foo;
        return g_;
    }
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I'm not looking to reorganize this code (yet, if ever). I'm trying to understand if existing code, written in the above pattern, has defined behavior or not.

Comment: @acm: Yes, sorry for this - not very useful - comment.